# Scatter Gather for One Way

Tags: mule

Mule 3.5 has replaced All router with Scatter Gather. I have a need to send payload to more than one message routes . Its one way and no need to aggregate the response. How would that be possible? The documentation all seem to be about request/response and aggregating data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add each one-way outbound endpoint in turn to your flow, like so:

```
<flow name="MyFlow">
    <set-payload value="Important Message" />
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="vm.inbox" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="jms.inbox" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="jms.inbox2" />
</flow>
```

In this flow, the payload "Important Message" will be sent to one VM queue and two JMS queues, in parallel.  The endpoints are one-way because VM and JMS transport are one-way by default.